# Recursion down DOM tree

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion

This is code from Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts.

```
var results = [];

var walkDOM = function (node,func) {
        func(node);                     //What does this do?
        node = node.firstChild;
        while(node) {
            walkDOM(node,func);
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }

    };
```

I understand the code except for `func(node)`. I guess the point is to pass `node` as a parameter in function `func`, but how will the browser understand it this way? `node` and `func` could be anything--so when the function is called it could read like this:

```
walkDOM(document.body,function(att) {
          node.getAttribute(att);
          results.push(node);
          });
```

When `func` is passed, `walkDOM` will process function(att) {...}(document.body)--which wouldn't make any sense. So why has Crockford chosen to include func(node)?

Comment: It is expected that the developer using `walkDOM` will pass it a function that *anticipates* receiving a DOM noted as the argument. Your function anticipates receiving an attribute name, and as such, wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: @patrick_dw--I still don't understand the notation of `func(node)`. Is the developer supposed to replace it with `function(node)`? And if not, how will `func(node)` make sense to the browser?

Comment: The browser doesn't need to make sense of it. Only the developer who wrote the function that was passed to `walkDOM` needs to make sense of it. If I want to walk the DOM, target every *text node*, and replace its text with *"patrick dw is sooooo good looking"*, then I would place that logic in the function I pass. The `walkDOM` will pass each node to *your* function (one at a time), and *your* function is responsible for doing something with that node.

Comment: ...remember, `func` is simply a reference to the very same function you passed to `walkDOM`. So `func( node )` is simply calling your function, and passing it the current node.

Comment: Did you eventually gain a complete understanding of the walkTheDOM code? If not, I would like to help.

Comment: The recursive function in the example includes the use of node.getAttribute simply to demonstrate to the noob student that not only nodes can be obtained, but their attributes as well.  It pre-empts the question 'if nodes can be accessed like this, can attributes?' - it is not complete code, which would include something like var attrVariable = node.getAttribute("class");  I guess you could iterate the results array and examine the attributes there, but what if you only wanted to return nodes into that array with attributes that match only a certain type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks to me like the `func` is used for doing something to every node in the tree.

For example, if I wanted to alert the tag name for every node in the entire tree:

```
walkDOM(document.body, function(node) {
    alert(node.tagName);
});
```

In your example function:

```
walkDOM(document.body,function(att) {
      node.getAttribute(att);
      results.push(node);
      });
```

... you have named the `node` parameter to `att`, but that doesn't magically make in a name of an attribute.  I would expect a "variable 'node' is not defined" when `node.getAttribute(att)` is ran, because node is being set to `att`... there is no `node` in that function's scope.

Answer (score 16):

Yes this tree traversal function makes sense since :

- the function argument is supposed to know how to handle (any) nodes
- the first call argument is supposed to be a supported node (not `document.body` for instance, if func doesn't know how to handle it)

That said, this algorithm still looks incorrect to me, as it only explores through the first sibling ; other siblings will be simply ignored. So I would recommend using this more traditional approach instead :

```
function walk(node, func) {
   var children = node.childNodes;
   for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)  // Children are siblings to each other
       walk(children[i], func);
   func(node);
}
```

Note that version is "deep first" (i.e. not calling call `func()` before processing children), but I'd rather recommend it since `func` is likely to change nodes. This way the processing of a parent will be able to consider the latest state of its already-processed children before issuing possibly un-appropriate changes.

Answer (score 3):

The `func` that's in the

```
func(node)
```

line is what is typically known as a *callback function*. It a function that is available for use by the `walkDOM` function. It might make sense with a more verbose function name:

```js
var results = [];

var walkDOM = function (node, iCanBeCalledOnANode) {
    iCanBeCalledOnANode(node); // Will be called on every DOM element 
    node = node.firstChild;
    while(node) {
        walkDOM(node,func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }

};
```

Hope this clears things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Crockford's code is passing a callback to walkDOM which can be used in many ways to process the arguments passed to it.

An example could be a method which returns the count of all DOM elements with the specified tagName:

```
var getTagNameCount = function(tagName) {
    var count = 0;
    walkDOM(document.body, function(node) {
       if (node.tagName === tagName) {
          count++;
       }
    });
    return count;
};
```