# Regexp to remove all html tags except <br>

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to make a regexp in javascript to remove ALL the html tags from an input string, except `<br>`.

I use `/(<([^>]+)>)/ig` for the tags and have tried a few things like adding [^(br)] to it, but I'm just getting confused now.

Could anyone help? I'm sure it's going to be a speed contest between SO gurus, so if the answer explains the logic of the expression, I'll choose it over the others.

**Edit :**

To all the 'don't do it' people, let me quote the following from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

> While it is true that asking regexes to parse arbitrary HTML is like asking Paris Hilton to write an operating system, it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML.

In this particular case, it's a bunch of text in a div, that stays consistent within many pages. I just want to get rid of a few cases (1% at most) where the users have included spans, strongs and a few other formatting tags. It is not worth more than the time to regexp it out as it barely happens over the thousands of pages I process. If you have a better, faster to implement idea, feel free to post it as an answer ;)

**Edit 2**

So many comments, I feel like adding a disclaimer : 
Using Regexp to parse HTML is **bad**. It will not work consistently and there are much better ways. Domparser has been mentioned; there's Cheerio or jsdom on Node.js, and a lot more libraries that will parse a HTML document correctly (in 99% cases). In that case, it is more like a string that happens to contain a few `<...>` that I needed to remove.

Comment: Tip: It's never a good idea to parse HTML content using Regular Expressions.

Comment: Obligatory don't do it link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1615483

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/616443

Comment: I would say that even an attempt at a valid html parser would be better. However this `<([^>]+)>` is not such an attempt. At the minimum you have to parse comments as well as generalized tag structure. I could put down a giant regex if you need it.

Comment: @sln it's not worth a generic parser, the data is the content of a div, already stored a a string in a db, and contains no comments, or strange structure. Just a few regular formatting tags. Thanks for your offer, part of me is curious to see this 'giant regexp' :) but it's not worth the trouble.

Comment: Its a mammoth regex, it floats and lives in people's nightmares all around the web.

Comment: @xShirase it may be better if you use e.g.`strip_tags` in _php_ **serverside**; if someone wants to put in HTML for malicious reasons and your only protection is _JavaScript_ you'll run into problems..

Comment: @PaulS the data is historical stuff, that needs to be reinjected in a new site, so there will be no new input. It's been saved in a very crappy way, and now pretty much cleaned up. No security concerns though.

Comment: `text = text.replace(/<(?!br\s*/?>)[^<>]*>/ig, '');` will do a pretty good job.

Comment: @ridgerunner Yup, that would be the right answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using :

```
.replace('<br>','%br%').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g,'')
```

then I split on the '%br%' instead of the regular br tag.
It is **not an HTML parser**, I am sure it will fail to parse 100% of the World Wide Web, and it solves my particular problem 100% of the time (just tried and tested).

Comment: You don't need the `i` modifier.

Comment: Will it remove this `<tag att1 = ">hello world" att2 = 'ab"c'/>` ?

Comment: @sln no it will not, but my dataset contained only <strong>, a few <span>, <i>, and a couple more.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
/(<((?!br)[^>]+)>)/ig
```

Comment: Just a point of interest. This regex will _not_ match any tag name that begins with `/br/i`

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse your string, then traverse it (I used the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6969604/2088135)), extracting the parts that you are interested in:

```js
var str = "<div>some text <span>some more</span><br /><a href='#'>a link</a>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var dom = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");
var text = "";
var walkDOM = function (node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkDOM(node,func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};

walkDOM(dom, function (node) {
    if (node.tagName === 'BR') {
        text += node.outerHTML;
    }
    else if (node.nodeType === 3) { // Text node
        text += node.nodeValue;
    }        
});

alert(text);
```

Comment: yes, that's what I want to avoid. My problem is not worth the include really ;) Thanks though, that's a cool snippet which will come in handy in the future.

Comment: No problem, feel free to upvote it if you find it useful. Personally I would recommend using this kind of approach as in the grand scheme of things, it's really not that many lines and it's much more flexible than any regular expression. It's worth getting out of the habit of using regex to solve this kind of problem and getting more experience of traversing HTML in a structured way.

Comment: I code scrapers for a living, so I use regular parsers all the time and I completely agree with you on the principle. In this case, just not worth it, a tiny script that I used once, and spent more time arguing about here than I spent coding it, has done the job. It's over. The grand scheme of things hasn't been disturbed, and natural order is restored. Guys, seriously, don't use regexp to parse HTML, it IS bad.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess the problem with this kind of question is that no-one other than you knows the exact format of the range of strings you are trying to work with, so it's impossible to know where a regex-based solution is going to fail. On the other hand, the parser-based approach is likely to succeed regardless.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. But, no matter the regex, it will fail to parse html.

```
 # /(?!<\/?br\s*\/?>)<[^>]+>/g

 (?! < /? br \s* /? > )
 < [^>]+ >
```

Comment: in this case, a regular html parser would be overkill, it's really a matter of a few tags