# How to have a regex that matches everything inside <> except <br>?

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex `text?.replace("<[^>]*>".toRegex(), "")` to ensure that if a String matches an HTML tag, it is removed. But I want to let `<br>` tag to not be replaced. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regexp to remove all html tags except <br>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877030/regexp-to-remove-all-html-tags-except-br)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
(?!<br>)(<[^>]*>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jvClB0/2/)

Or:

```
<(?!br)[^>]*>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jvClB0/3/)

Comment: What about `<(?!br)[^>]*>`?