# Program recursion in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I am a beginner at javascript. I want to use javascript to browse all the elements in the dom and print its name, I wrote the following:

```
function getNumber(parent){
                var entiredoc = parent;
                var docnodes = entiredoc.childNodes;
                return docnodes.length;
            }
function browAllDom(parent){
      if(parent!=null){
            for(i = 0; i < getNumber(parent); i++){
                    alert(parent.nodeName);
                    return browAllDom(parent.childNodes[i]);
            }
      }
}
```

when I debug, it browses the leaf in the tree dom and exits. I think it has to browse all in the for loop.

Where's the problem? And how can I you fix it?

Comment: `return browAllDom(parent.childNodes[i]);` ... means that the loop will run at most one time ... return returns out of enclosing function

Comment: An easy way would be to use `parent.getElementsByTagName('*')`, that returns a flattened object of all elements in `parent`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will run only a single time:

```
for(i = 0; i < getNumber(parent); i++){
    (parent.nodeName);
    return browAllDom(parent.childNodes[i]);
}
```

This code will run only once since you are returning from the for loop.

Instead you should write the return outside of the for loop.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14858238/1475228). You will have a better understanding.